# NOT LIKE and LIKE not returning opposite result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-like

I have a table with 200 records out of which 10 records has text containing the word 'TAX'.

When I'm executing

```
Select * from tbl1 WHERE [TextCol] LIKE '%TAX%'
```

then I get the result set with those 10 records correctly .

But when I am trying to exclude those records by

```
Select * from tbl1 WHERE [TextCol] NOT LIKE '%TAX%'
```

it's returning 100 records only, instead of 190.

Comment: Do you have `null` values for that column at all?

Comment: Yes, there are null values in that column

Comment: Try avoiding to use `%` at the beginning of your search string when possible. It is quite heavy.

Comment: @MoslemBenDhaou There are ways to optimize infix queries. I believe the primary method in SQL Server is the Full Text Search mechanism, but I may be unaware of better options. In PostgreSQL, you can use trigram indexes to make them efficient. For a table of 200 rows, though, it probably isn't even worth indexing.

Comment: What? MySQL is "teen-vocabulary" compliant?

Comment: The 90 'missing' records in the NOT LIKE result regards to null values into the tested column. From my 'personal logic' I also find weird that null value won't match NOT LIKE (because it does match!) but this is how MSSQL works.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Does this return the correct result ?

```
Select * from tbl1 WHERE COALESCE([TextCol],'-1') NOT LIKE '%TAX%'
```

I believe `NULL` values are the issue here, if the column contains them, then `NULL NOT LIKE '%TAX%'` will return `UNKNOWN/NULL` and therefore won't be selected.

I advise you to read about [handling with `NULL` values](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp) , or [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191504(v=sql.105).aspx).

As @ughai suggested, if performance is an issue you can also use:

```
  Select * from tbl1 
  WHERE [TextCol] NOT LIKE '%TAX%'
     OR [TextCol] IS NULL
```

Comment: I would suggest using `[TextCol] NOT LIKE '%TAX%' OR [TextCol] IS NULL` as it would have better performance if the user wants to include `NULL` values

Comment: He said "190 records", so I doubt performace is an issue, but edited anyway as others might read this answer @ughai .

Comment: Thanks! NULL was the issue.

Comment: "then `NULL NOT LIKE '%TAX%'` will return false" -- No, it won't. If it returned false, then it would be trivial to work around the problem by putting the `NOT` at a higher level: `NOT(NULL LIKE '%TAX%')` would return true if `NULL LIKE '%TAX%'` returned false. Instead, it returns unknown. Unknown also means the row won't be selected.

Comment: It's not "if performance is an issue", that's also the obviously clearer version of the code. Saves people puzzling out where "-1" comes from.

Answer (score 18):

**(A)** SQL comparison operators result in three possible values: True, False and Unknown. If one or both operands are `NULL` then the result is Unknown. Consider the following example where we compare some values (a person's age) with a constant (18):

```
21   >= 18 -- True
15   >= 18 -- False
NULL >= 18 -- Unknown
```

As you can see, the database can/will not decide if `NULL` is greater than/equal to 18.

**(B)** The database will only return rows where the `WHERE` clause evaluates to True. Inverting the expression (e.g. `WHERE age >= 18` changed to `WHERE age < 18`) does not affect Unknown results.

You can use the [`IS [NOT] NULL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188795.aspx) to match `NULL` values. The following query will select the rows where the column does not match the pattern OR the column is NULL:

```
WHERE [TextCol] NOT LIKE '%TAX%' OR [TextCol] IS NULL
```

Functions such as `ISNULL` and `COALESCE` can be used to transform `NULL` into some value.

Comment: Correction: All operations involving `NULL` values result in **`UNKNOWN`** ...except when they don't e.g. `SELECT COUNT(TextCol) AS tally FROM tbl1`

Comment: Your edit 'all operations' -> 'comparison operators' is good +1

Answer (score 0):

1. ```
   Select * from tbl1 
   WHERE ([TextCol] NOT LIKE '%TAX%') AND ([TextCol] NOT LIKE '%TAX%')
   ```
2. ```
   select * from tbl1
   where [TextCol] NOT LIKE '%TAX%' OR [TextCol] IS NULL
   ```

Comment: What's the point of `WHERE ([TextCol] NOT LIKE '%TAX%') AND ([TextCol] NOT LIKE '%TAX%')` ?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation [really helps](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the `IN` operator on simple int column with nulls.
I found that these where not each others inverse as I thought. (I could tell by the row count)

```
select * from Dest where id in(select id from Source)
select * from Dest where id NOT in(select id from Source)
```

To get each others invert I had too rewrite them as such:

```
select * from Dest where isnull(id,-2)  in(select isnull(id,-1) from Source) 
select * from Dest where isnull(id,-2) NOT in(select isnull(id,-1) from Source)
```