# SQL Select one statement expect values start with

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following code here:

```
SELECT productcode, Brand, product, size
from outerbarcodes i
where productcode = '' or productcode is null or
     brand = '' or brand is null or
     product = '' or product is null or
     size = '' or size is null;
```

Id like to add a condition not to include values that start with `'PK'` inside column productcode. How would the code be amended?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @vc74 MySQL doesn't work that way.

Comment: Im refering it to MySQL Workbench

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select productcode, Brand, product, size
from outerbarcodes i
where (productcode = '' or productcode is null or
       brand = '' or brand is null or
       product = '' or product is null or
       size = '' or size is null
      ) and
      productcode not like 'PK%';
```

I'm a little confused by the other answers, because they are changing the comparisons for the other columns -- instead of checking for empty columns, they are checking for columns that have values.

Comment: Sorry, thats the correct code you have just given. Sorry didnt realise what was going on. Well spotted on other answers

Comment: what does the 'i' represent after `from outerbarcodes i`

Comment: @Eduards . . . It is a table alias.  You can qualify the column names by using it, for example, `i.productcode`.  Because the query has only one table reference, qualifying the column names is more optional.

Comment: Thats going to be very useful for me to know, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

use `not like` operator

```
`SELECT productcode, Brand, product, size
 from outerbarcodes i
 where ((productcode = '' or productcode is null) and productcode not like 'PK%') or
      (brand = '' or brand is null) or
      (product = '' or product is null) or
      (size = '' or size is null);`
```

Comment: You don't need all those parentheses :-)

Answer (score 1):

You may just add a `LIKE` condition to your current where clause:

```
SELECT productcode, Brand, product, size
FROM outerbarcodes i
WHERE
    (productcode > '' AND productcode NOT LIKE 'PK%') OR
    brand > '' OR
    product > '' OR
    size > '';
```

Comment: I have just tested it and it does makes sense using the operator not like 'pk%'. It still returns the values starting with 'PK'. Im gonna have a read on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40376260/not-like-and-like-not-returning-opposite-result something to do with null values...

Comment: @Eduards You should add sample data to your question.  My logic looks correct to me, at least based on what my interpretation of your question is.

Comment: I totally agree with you Tim, I believe its something to do with null values that causes this issue. I have posted an answer with the code I have just used. And it works perfectly fine. Ill just have to amend it to not show null values